# all Derived classes must implement their own destructor functions, otherwise report compile error?

Tags: c++, oop, c++11, inheritance

Recently interviewer asked me following question
"Derived classes allowed to inherit from base class but all derived classes must implement user defined destructor. **If derived class does not define user define destructor, report compile error**.
"
Any idea, how to solve this problem ?

---

Thought of solving this problem by using **pure virtual destructor** in Base class, but it does not solve the problem.

For below code, I want compiler to report an error since derived class does not implement user defined destructor

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual ~Base() = 0;
};

Base::~Base()
{
    cout << "Base destructor" << endl;
}

*//expecting an error here, since no user defined destructor*
class Derived : public Base 
{
};

int main()
{
    Derived d;
}
```

Comment: Which your current approach does *if you instantiate `Derived` or `Base`*

Comment: I guess by "but all derived classes must implement destructor" you mean all derived classes must have a user defined destructor? Because `Derived` implements  destructor, it is just that you don't see it.

Comment: Well, I guess it's practically impossible. The base class destructor gets called anyway.

Comment: Yes, user defined destructor

Comment: What an idiotic interview question. Why didn't you ask him how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to enforce an explicitly declared destructor using exceptions specifications

```
class Enforcer {
  class InnerEnforcer {
  };
protected:
  ~Enforcer() throw(InnerEnforcer) {
    std::cout << "Enforcer::dtor" << std::endl;
  }
};

class Base : public virtual Enforcer {
public:
  virtual ~Base() throw() {
    std::cout << "Base::dtor" << std::endl;
  }
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
  //~Derived() throw() { std::cout << "Derived:dtor" << std::endl; }
};

int main() {
  Derived d;

  Base* b = new Derived();
  delete b;

  return 0;
}
```

This code will not compile with the error 'looser throw specifier for virtual Derived::~Derived() throw(Enforcer::InnerEnforcer)'. Uncommenting the line will compile with no errors.

EDIT: changed `class Base : virtual Enforcer` to `class Base : public virtual Enforcer`

Comment: Not correct.   This approach will prevent `Derived` being instantiated, regardless of whether its destructor is declared or defined, due to a base class having a (to `Derived`) inaccessible destructor.